# Android Branch Deeplinks not working from within Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, branch.io

I have Branch.io deeplinking implemented in my App. Everything used to work fine, but recently (not sure how long ago, just noticed), when links are clicked from within the FB App, the returned **branchUniversalObject** is always **null**. The following code snippet is implemented and if the same link is clicked from any other App (messenger, slack, browser, etc...) the **branchUniversalObject** is valid and everything works as expected. I even copied the link from the FB post and pasted it into the browser and the **branchUniversalObject** was **non-null** then.

```
branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchUniversalReferralInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject, LinkProperties linkProperties, BranchError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "setupBranch: onInitiFinished: branchUniversalObject: " + branchUniversalObject);
            if (error == null && branchUniversalObject != null) {
                HashMap<String,String> branchMetadata = branchUniversalObject.getMetadata();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    if (Session.isGuestMode()) {
                        bundle.put(.....)
                        jumpToLogin(bundle);
                    } else {
                        bundle.put(.....);
                        BranchUtils.startBranchSubscribe(bundle);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Did FB change something in their App how they are handling link clicks? And if so, is there something that needs to be done on the Android App side?

Seems to work fine in the iOS version of the App.

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io: this is not expected behavior. We just tried this with our own testbed apps and everything is working as expected, so it sounds like some sort of configuration issue unique to your app.

Would you mind [writing a ticket for our Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) so we can get to the bottom of this?